# Dynamic Paint Ocean with Shrinkwrap

Tags: modifiers, dynamic-paint, shrinkwrap, ocean-simulation

This is close to the common ocean + dyn. paint problem but i wanted to take it a step further unfortunately.
So i want to create an animation with several floating ships that travel along their paths.
The first problem i ran into was that the shrinkwrap modifier on the shippath also replicated the movement on the waves of the dynamic paint which ended in a total mess.
My attempt right now is to have a tracking ocean which is invisible and provides the ocean-wave movement. Then have a simple plane (subdivided) on top which acts as the display-ocean with material and the dynamic paint modifier. To replicate the waves from the tracking-ocean i am using a shrinkwrap modifier on the display-ocean. binding the shippaths to the tracking-ocean gets rid of the dynamic paint interaction. but the shrinkwrap on the display ocean has the unfortunate effect that also the waves created by the dynamic paint get wrapped to the tracking ocean which doesn't work at all.

how do i solve this?
i want to have my ships driving, while tracking the movement of the ocean while they also can create waves. i would either need a solution in that the dynamic paint can't affect the shippath-alignment on the ocean (like 2 identical oceans without any dependencies in between them) or a solution to just display or project the waves onto the tracking-ocean.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, uour question was a bit confusing so I didn't really understand if you already tried that, but you can use an ocean modifier with lower detail settings as your shrinkwraped object, and disable it for rendering. This will reduce jitter caused by high frequency waves

Comment: Sorry its a bit hard to explain. I have shippaths that shrinkwrap to the ocean to replicate the wave-movement, otherwise the ships will just run unnaturally through the waves. I cannot use the dynamic paint and ocean modifier on this same object, the ripples ahead are transfered to the shippath which ends in a total mess.